# One particular user alone not synced to Ranger from LDAP

Tags: hadoop, active-directory, ldap, apache-ranger

We are using LDAP/AD sync source to sync users from LDAP to Apache Ranger.
But as per our observation, only one particular user is not syncing to Ranger.

We cross verified and confirmed that user is present at LDAP side with proper data as other users.

What might be causing the issue?

Comment: There are probably some requirements to be met in order to correctly sync/replicate users (like having an email address, being member of a group, or having a specific role), so if in AD this particular user's entry is missing some of the required fields, or if one of these fields for some reason contains an "invalid" value (invalid for Ranger), it might be causing this issue. There should be some logs to dig into, can you check and add any interesting lines ?

Comment: I agree with you @EricLavault But the same user is perfectly synced with Ranger in Production environment. The problem is with non-prod environment only.